# Malformed Line 59

Tags: apt, updates

I've seen a bunch of post about malformed line but I can't understand how they are resolved or what needs to be changed

and now I'm getting another error message:

(gedit:2708): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

How can I resolve the Malformed line issue and get rid of the new issue that is happening?

please use muggle words. I'm a noob.

Comment: line 58 - deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

line 59 - deb http://archive.canonical.com/trusty partner
line 60 - # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/trusty partner

Comment: Change line 59 to be `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner`.

Comment: that solved it! granted I had to change line 61 too but it did the trick. thanks!

Comment: @JeKi Can you add a short answer, so the question does not stay open?

Answer (score -1):

After adding a space between the last `/` and the word next to it, it resolved the issue.